# how to repair a git rebase that should have been a git merge

Tags: git, merge

For a web development project, I have the following branches:

- *trunk* : the main branch, where all new feature end up merged
- *deploy* : the branch with server-specific deployment settings

At every deployment the *trunk* branch is merged into the *deploy* branch, integrating latest developments into deployment.

The issue is that during the last deployment, I did, while on the *deploy* branch

> git rebase origin/trunk

instead of

> git merge origin/trunk

Now i'm trying to do a new deployment and to do the merge but it all goes hell, and conflicts can't seem to resolve.

**Any idea how I could clean up my *deploy* branch?**

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to undo the rebase on your *deploy* branch.

Find where the rebase happened:

```
git checkout deploy
git reflog
```

Then reset using the found reference:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{N}
```

Be aware this will undo all the work you did in the *deploy* branch after the reference.

Comment: git reflog does not work in this case, since everyhing has been pushed to origin already. I think of 1. finding out the last merge, 2. 'git reset --hard ...' on it, 3. git merge origin/trunk on deploy branch. Would it make sense?

Comment: @Electrogramme: did you push _deploy_ to _origin_? If yes, reset as I said and push again using `--force`. This way you'll overwrite _origin_. Let me know how it goes. IMPORTANT: Be sure to backup everything first, so you don't lose your work if something goes wrong.